# NetBeans RCP with JavaFX Integration

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-platform

I need to make an image management application in Netbeans RCP with JavaFX Integration, but don't know how to make this? Can anyone tell me how I can start this application. Thanks

Comment: A tutorial, https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-javafx.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use JFXPanel.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html

RCP is swing based but you can use FX nodes in that panel.